# Manual pages for Ruby functions from command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, manuals

Is there a way to get at the manuals of Ruby functions from the command line?

Like the `?func` man pages in R.

Comment: Do you mean man pages? I have old ones posted here http://douglasallen.github.io/Ruby_core_ri_doc/ Genuine works from 'Matz'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `ri` tool might help here.](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_ri_tool.html)

```
ri Array  
ri Array.sort  
ri Hash#each  
ri Math::sqrt
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the following shell script that I use because it does color formatting in the terminal:

```
wesbailey@feynman:~/insiderpages> cat `which rim`
ri -Tf ansi -w 150 $1
wesbailey@feynman:~/insiderpages> rim Array
```

...